# What kind of test shall I use in my spring project(and am I doing it right)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, junit, mockito

My project is a simple management system for shop which is connected to MySQL database.

I only have JUnit test like this one(is this test written correctly?):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class EmployeeRepositoryIntegrationTest
{
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Test
    public void whenFindByLastName_thenReturnEmployee()
    {
        User employee = new User("UserName","password","John",
                        "Smith","Adress Test","123123123","CityTest");

        entityManager.persist(employee);
        entityManager.flush();

        User result = userRepository.findUserByLastName(employee.getLastName()).get(0);
        assertThat(result.getLastName()).isEqualTo(employee.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Should I add Mockito Tests, and what kind of test should I add in future?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid Mockito to test you JPA repoistories.

Better to seed an in-memory database (which can be spun up and torn down) with real test data.

If you're using the @DataJpaTest annotation you're expected to use sql to seed your database, look at this [@DataJpaTest example](http://zetcode.com/springboot/datajpatest/). You can use sql files and get rid of the TestEntityManager.

Take a look at this [DBUnit example](https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/sample.html). You add your test data in an XML file in your resources directory.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for showing the right way to test my project!
I'll definitely use it in my tests.